# I am using GoogleApiclient to get location lattitude longitude but getting wrong lattitude longitude many time. how to resolve it?

Tags: geolocation, latitude-longitude

Please Give me some solution to get accurate location even inside the building.

Comment: Please help yourself. Edit your question to show examples of what you got, what you expected to get, and what was the basis of your expectation.

Comment: Thanks for your response @John Machin .I am expecting accurate location data. Suppose I am travelling through train and I am sending my location data to server in background service of my application. somewhere it sends accurate lattitude longitude to server and somewhere the lattitude longitude is very far from my real location. so I need solution regarding that.

Comment: Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): without (1) **the code** you are using, and (2) **an example of input** producing a wrong output (and (3) **what the "right output" should be**) there is no way for people to help you.